# C++ Access key value pairs in map without iterators

Tags: c++, dictionary

I need to check if two `std::map`s contain the same keys and values so I need a way to access the key value pairs of both `std::map`s. I know that `std::map`s have the `==` operator but my `std::map` contains objects in the value field that don't have a defined `==` operator. It would also be too difficult to make an `==` operator for the object because it contains pointers to other objects I would need to define `==` for.

Is there a way of getting key value pairs without iterators or a better way of trying to do what I'm describing?

Comment: How are you going to tell if the values are the same if you don't have an `==` operator or something similar?

Comment: You have to become clear about what _same values_ does mean for you. You are free to define how a custom equality operator shall work. It may consider pointer member variables to call the equality operators for the pointees as well. It may as well ignore certain members if they are not relevant for equality. If you are not able to describe the equality yourself - how do you think the compiler should be? If you are able - you may tell the compiler - by providing the resp. custom `operator==()`s.

Comment: @Mat For this specific case I only need to check if certain member variables of the object are equal

Comment: @Scheff That is true but this is for a very specific test and I've been told that we should avoid adding this code, i.e. it's not my call.

Comment: Then you still have the option to write a loop which inspects all key/value pairs according to your needs...

Comment: @Scheff can you elaborate?

Comment: You can pass iterators and a custom comparator to [std::equal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal)